# Which question on SFF has the highest number of downvotes?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes

As the title asks: **Which question is the most heavily downvoted on our site?**

If someone knows of a *script* that measures this, then by all means point it out to me :-)

Comment: Can I ask why you would like to know?

Comment: Interesting prize to win, I guess :P

Comment: @Mooz Whenever I myself get downvoted, it would obviously be consoling to look at said question for comfort.

Comment: @Mooz -- The topic came up in chat re: another stack. I was merely curious. :)

Comment: Relevant - [Lowest-scoring question of all time (including deleted questions)](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10036/lowest-scoring-question-of-all-time-including-deleted-questions)

Comment: I think this is duplicate

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've forked "Most Downvoted Answers" to show the [most downvoted questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/520057/most-downvoted-answers).

**The top 5 (at the last edit)**

1) [What is “DON'T PANIC” a reference to on the dashboard of Elon Musk's car?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180869/what-is-dont-panic-a-reference-to-on-the-dashboard-of-elon-musks-car) (**71** downvotes)
2) [Is Captain America gay?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114500/is-captain-america-gay) (**48** downvotes)
3) [Has George R. R. Martin described the color of Daenerys' pubic hair in any book?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142810/has-george-r-r-martin-described-the-color-of-daenerys-pubic-hair-in-any-book) (**40** downvotes)
4) [What is JK Rowling “bad” at?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140363/what-is-jk-rowling-bad-at) (**36** downvotes)
Joint 5) [What is Hermione Granger's ethnicity?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105467) (**32** downvotes)
Joint 5) [Why do castle gates in GoT open inwards?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164018/why-do-castle-gates-in-got-open-inwards) (**32** downvotes)
Joint 7) [Was Bilbo's sexuality ever referred to by Tolkien?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147383/was-bilbos-sexuality-ever-referred-to-by-tolkien) (**30** downvotes)
Joint 7) [What is Kylo Ren's relationship with Darth Vader?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111540/what-is-kylo-rens-relationship-with-darth-vader) (**30** downvotes)
Joint 9) [If Darth Vader is Luke Skywalker's father, who is Luke's mother?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132190/if-darth-vader-is-luke-skywalkers-father-who-is-lukes-mother) (**29** downvotes)
Joint 12) [Did Draco Malfoy sexually assault Hermione Granger?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144298/did-draco-malfoy-sexually-assault-hermione-granger) (**26** downvotes)
Joint 12)  [In The Matrix, why did humans scorch the sky to block sunshine?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12377/in-the-matrix-why-did-humans-scorch-the-sky-to-block-sunshine)(**26** downvotes)
Joint 12)  [Why are most of the main characters White/English in Game Of Thrones?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59521/why-are-most-of-the-main-characters-white-english-in-game-of-thrones)(**26** downvotes)

---

You can also see the lowest number of votes *on aggregate* (e.g. upvotes **and** downvotes) using the standard [vote sort](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) tool.

In that case, the order is

1) [Is Captain America gay?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114500/is-captain-america-gay) (**-37** = 48 down, 11 up)
Joint 2) [What is Kylo Ren's relationship with Darth Vader?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111540/what-is-kylo-rens-relationship-with-darth-vader) (**-26** = 30 down, 4 up)
Joint 2) [Has George R. R. Martin described the color of Daenerys' pubic hair in any book?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142810/has-george-r-r-martin-described-the-color-of-daenerys-pubic-hair-in-any-book) (**-26** = 40 down, 14 up)
Joint 4) [Did Draco Malfoy sexually assault Hermione Granger?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144298/did-draco-malfoy-sexually-assault-hermione-granger) (**-24** = 26 down, 2 up)
Joint 4)  [If Darth Vader is Luke Skywalker's father, who is Luke's mother?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132190/if-darth-vader-is-luke-skywalkers-father-who-is-lukes-mother) (**-24** = 29 down, 5 up)
Joint 6) [Was Voldemort an idiot?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134095/was-voldemort-an-idiot) (**-23** = 25 down, 2 up)
Joint 6) [What's the in-universe explanation for the change of face of Bruce Banner?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87515/whats-the-in-universe-explanation-for-the-change-of-face-of-bruce-banner) (**-23** = 26 down, 3 up)

Comment: I seem to be getting more than my fair share of downvotes at the moment.; http://replygif.net/i/718.gif

Comment: If you've found a way to convert rep into money,  Jack B Nimble will be very interested...

Comment: @ancientswordrage - Throwaway high rep accounts - £50 for 20000 rep.

Comment: Ah, the classic hot button topics: sexuality, race, and parental relationships in Star Wars.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - and questions that are just plain dumb

Comment: @roguejedi - There has to be a way of dynamically updating these figures....

Comment: Although I didn't know the topics that would come up, I'm completely unsurprised that sexuality and race came up. Personally, I think those are legitimate questions. LOL, I suppose all those downvotes would indicate otherwise! :)

Comment: Your final link doesn’t take you where is says it will take you. :/

Comment: @edlothiad - Cheers for the edit

Answer (score 13):

You can use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer to do this kind of thing:

```
SELECT TOP 10 PostId, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM Votes v
INNER JOIN Posts p ON p.Id = v.PostId 
WHERE v.VoteTypeId = 3 AND p.PostTypeId = 1
GROUP BY PostId
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

The most heavily downvoted question (that has not yet been deleted) is post 114500 with 40 downvotes; that post is:

[Is Captain America gay?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114500/is-captain-america-gay)

Comment: +1 Thank you -- Where is the data explorer located? I'll bookmark it. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess http://data.stackexchange.com. You can search queries other people have made, but in order to get the most out of it you really need to learn a little bit of [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL). Monica Cellio wrote a [nice tutorial](http://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial), if you're so inclined