# Lowest-scoring question of all time (including deleted questions)

Tags: support, down-votes

Someone recently asked which question on SFF had [the most downvotes](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10017/which-question-on-sff-has-the-highest-number-of-downvotes). Of course, it is trivial to determine which question has the lowest *total* score: just order by votes.

However, this does not tell us what is the lowest-scoring question there has ever been, since a question that scored so low might well have been deleted.

**Is there any way to determine what is the lowest-scoring question SFF has *ever* had, including questions that are now deleted?**

Comment: Relevant: [Which question on SFF has the highest number of downvotes?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10017/which-question-on-sff-has-the-highest-number-of-downvotes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for;

**[Deleted questions with score](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/382201/deleted-questions-with-score)**

---

If you run the search (and you've got over 10K rep), you can review the questions that were low voted *and subsequently deleted* (correct as of 11/03/17)

1) [Did Draco Malfoy rape Hermione Granger? [duplicate]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144396/did-draco-malfoy-rape-hermione-granger) (**-28** = 28 down, 0 up)
2) [Did Draco rape Hermione? [duplicate]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150952/did-draco-rape-hermione) (**-23** = 23 down, 0 up)
3) [Do imaginary animals; dragons, unicorns, etc… exist in the real world? [closed]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19245/do-imaginary-animals-dragons-unicorns-etc-exist-in-the-real-world)  (**-21** = 22 down, 1 up)
4) [Who is the new 'Darth Vader 2.0' character? [deleted]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105523/who-is-the-new-darth-vader-2-0-character)  (**-19** = 27 down, 6 up)
5) [I KNOW WHO KILLED PHONE GUY IN FNAF 1 [closed]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128868/i-know-who-killed-phone-guy-in-fnaf-1) (**-18** = 18 down, 0 up)
5) [Is this a valid explanation for why the TARDIS blew up? Also could Davros be the TARDIS controller [closed]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/44845/is-this-a-valid-explanation-for-why-the-tardis-blew-up-also-could-davros-be-the)  (**-18** = 18 down, 0 up)

---

Had these questions survived, the topmost would have come in at #3 on the list of the [5 most downvoted questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10017/which-question-on-sff-has-the-highest-number-of-downvotes) of all time. The top two would have made the top 5 *aggregate* list (e.g. upvotes v. downvotes) coming in at #2 and #3, respectively.

**I guess because in order for a question to be [truly despised](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114500/is-captain-america-gay), it needs to not get deleted for at least a while.**